# Circular dependency detected when installing Nuget package, Akavache 6.0.0-alpha0038

Tags: nuget, circular-dependency, akavache

I'm getting a **'Circular dependency detected'** error when I'm trying to install **Akavache 6.0.0-alpha0038** into my Xamarin.IOs project in Visual Studio 2017.

This is the error in detail,

```
Error       Circular dependency detected 'akavache 6.0.0-alpha0038 => akavache.core 6.0.0-alpha0038 => System.Reactive 3.1.1 => System.Reactive.PlatformServices 4.0.0-preview00001 => System.Reactive 3.1.1'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your visual studio, open **Options Menu** (Tools > Options),

Then, Under, **NuGet Package Manager > General**, choose ***PackageReference*** as the *Default package management format* for Package Management *(refer image)*

[image]

Now try installing the nuget package, in this case **Akavache 6.0.0-alpha0038**.

Worked for me

**Note:** You have to remove *packages.config* file if it exists. You can remove the file, then install the package, then re-add the file.

Comment: Just a bit more info about why this works. 

The resolver for packages.config and PackageReference restore styles work differently.
Packages.config does the resolution only at install time and tries to resolve all dependencies! It obeys the "nearest first" rule to a tee, and if it happens that leads to a circular dependency, so be it. 

PackageReference is smarter in that it will try to resolve some of these conflicts and bump-up or bump down some versions.

Answer (score 0):

Open nuget manager
select package
open options and select dropdown from 'install and update optoins' -'Ignore Dependency'
Same way for uninstall

[image]